# Matlab : plot latitude and longitude

Tags: matlab

I want to plot latitude and longitude as a node and there will be edge to connect the node. I want to show map in the background of graph. How can I do that ?

Comment: to start: buy the mapping toolbox

Comment: I was preferring any free tools.

Comment: Try to get started yourself first by using things like `help plot` and let us know when you get stuck.

Comment: Is there any free toolbox. Because I am trying to do that as simple as possible. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking at something along the lines of:

```
figure
image(...)
hold
plot(...)
```

where you use the image function to display your map, and plot (or similar function) to display your latitude/longitude data however it is you want (you're not very specific about that).

You will probably have to play with axes properties in order to get the scaling right and get your plot in the right place relative to your map, but it depends on your data.